# Default value in an iterationcombo box

Tags: rally

Is there any way i can have the current iteration selected (based on the current month/date and comparing it with the start/end dates of the iteration that fall in that month) when the iteration box is loaded. This is to avoid having the user select the iteration and that "change" event then triggering my custom app.

In short i need to configure the iteration combo box to always default to the current iteration, and treat this default as a change event and have the app execute the on ready/change function.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the default behavior:

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.combobox.TimeboxComboBox-cfg-defaultToCurrentTimebox

Is it not behaving that way?  Maybe you can share a bit more code?

Comment: had placed the configuration a bit out of place. arranged it, and it worked